# Add custom fields to Author Information in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, add-filter

I'm looking for a way to add custom fields and display them (without plugin).

I've found [a great example](http://davidwalsh.name/add-profile-fields) on the web. The author adds a number of custom fields by adding the following function to the `fuctions.php` file:

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {

    // Add new fields
    $profile_fields['linkedin'] = 'LinkedIn URL';
    $profile_fields['telephone'] = 'Telephone';        
    return $profile_fields;
}

add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```

I've been able to successfully add such fields to the **Contact Information** section of my user registration form. I've been trying to add custom fields to other sections, like the **Author Information** section (where the Bio is), but without success.

I think that I've to change the value `user_contactmethods` in the `add_filter(...)` function, but I have not been able to find anything.

I do not even know if this is the correct way to do this, but it worked so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are new to wordpress, You don't have knowledge about the `filter` and `action`. If you go through the [filter list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) , You will find `user_contactmethods` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Author_and_User_Filters).

As you can see in **Author and User Filters**, there are only 4 filters for Author and User. And we can use none of them to achieve your desired output.

But somehow we can do it by adding another field under the **About the User** something like **Author Information**.

```
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

    function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Author Information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
    <th><label for="author"><?php _e("Author Information"); ?></label></th>
    <td>
    <textarea name="author" id="author" rows="5" cols="10" ><?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'author', $user->ID ) ); ?></textarea><br />
    <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter Author's Information."); ?></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php }

    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

    function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'author', $_POST['author'] );
    }
```

So in that way you can add as many field as you want.

Comment: Wow, that definitely solved my problem. Time to gain some knowledge about fileters and actions then!